# Generate two CHANGELOG files (CHANGELOG.md and USER-CHANGELOG.md) using semantic-release

Tags: changelog, semantic-release

I have successfully generated CHANGELOG.md using semantic-release and github actions. Also I am able to customize the CHANGELOG.md using templates(I added the commit body under the commit title). Now I want to generate USER-CHANGELOG.md after generating the CHANGELOG.md.

I have tried some ways like replacing certain string inside the release.config.js(changing CHANGELOG.md into USER-CHANGELOG.md and also the path to the template because the USER-CHANGELOG.md will have a different format than CHANGELOG.md) so that the 2nd run of semantic-release will also run the release.config.js but with different configuration. But the problem is it says no changes found or no commits to publish because the first run of semantic-release have already committed and pushed the changes. Also when I created 2 separate jobs and run them on the same time it says

```
[remote rejected] v1.1.0-alpha.30 -> v1.1.0-alpha.30 (cannot lock ref 'refs/tags/v1.1.0-alpha.30': reference already exists)
```

So maybe some of you have solved this or maybe you can point me to the right direction on how to implement this.